# Switch around two products generated by widget

Tags: magento-1.9, product, widget

In my CMS page, I am using widget to display two products:

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="2" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Is there an easy way to switch the places of these two products?

UPDATE

Or, is there a way to call a product just by ID? That way, I can display the 2 products just singular by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might help you.

The block for displaying new product is:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php
```

see the function _beforeToHtml() default sorting is done by start date descending:

```
->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
```

You can copy this block to code/local and replace it with position or the sort order you want.

Comment: Is there no way by using the CMS system, or changing templates?